# Need click event of the image which is to be displayed in table view in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone

I need a click event on the image which is added by cell's addSubview method and sets favourite and unfavourite flag in table view. Please note that i don't need cell's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to achieve this task. Refer below  code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    myImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Favourite.png"];
    UIImageView *imgName = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:myImage];
    imgName.frame = CGRectMake(270, 10, 25, 25);
    [cell addSubview:imgName];


    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello";

    return cell;
}
```

How i got click event on the imgName ?

Comment: You can declare abutton and set the image to the button and then use a ibaction to create a click.

Comment: I would think we are talking about taps. Clicks do not exist in UIKit.

Comment: Thanks XCode Monkey : Your solution works for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a subclass of UITableViewCell. Give it as a property the UIImageView. Then in that subclass, add a UITapgestureRecognizer to the UIIMageView and have it call some selector on self (e.g. -(void) imageViewTapped: (id) sender).
Give the subclass a property 'delegate', and make it adopt to a protocol that is defined in the .h file of the UITableViewCell. Add a method like

```
- (void) imageViewTappedOnTableViewCell: (YourSubclassOfUITableViewCell *) cell;
```

This method can then be called on the delegate in the selector (e.g. imageViewTapped:) that you added to the tap recognizer.
Back in the viewControllers cellForRowAtIndexPath: you can set the delegate of the cell to be that viewController. Then on the viewController implement the method from the protocol. As you are send the cell that was tapped as argument, you can ask the tableView for the indexPath of that cell and act accordingly.

Very clear design, and exactly what you are looking for (note that didSelectCellForRowAtIndexPath: is almost doing the same conceptual t (hing, except that it gives you the indexPath instead of the cell).